# How do I update JSON file using PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell, powershell-3.0

I have one json file `mytest.json` like below I want to update values using `PowerShell script`

update.json

```
{
    "update": [
        {
            "Name": "test1",        
            "Version": "2.1"
        },
        {
            "Name": "test2",        
            "Version": "2.1"
        }   
    ]
}
```

I want to write a PowerShell script where `if Name=="test1" I want to update Version= "3"`
How can i do it using parameters?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Here is a way :

```
$a = Get-Content 'D:\temp\mytest.json' -raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$a.update | % {if($_.name -eq 'test1'){$_.version=3.0}}
$a | ConvertTo-Json -depth 32| set-content 'D:\temp\mytestBis.json'
```

According to  @FLGMwt and @mikemaccana  I improve the `ConvertTo-Json` with `-depth 32` because the default depth value is 2 and for object deeper than 2 you will receive class informations in spite of objects.

Comment: Be ware that `ConvertTo-Json` has a default depth of 2. Deep json will get `ToString`'d which is probably not what you want.

If you have more nested json, use the `Depth` parameter: `ConvertTo-Json -Depth 20`

Comment: Reference for the `depth` issue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-6

Comment: @mikemaccana Thanks for the adjusting with `depth`, but 1000 is a bit to important. I also add a small explanation.

Answer (score 17):

I have also faced the same kind of issue. I was looking to change the records of the below JSON file

```
{
"SQS_QUEUE_URL":  "https://que-url.com/server1",
"SQS_EVENTS_QUEUE_URL":  "https://events-server.com/server1/development_events",
"REGION":  "region1",
"BUCKET":  "test-bucket",
"AE_WORK_PATH":  "C:\\workpath\\path1",
"ENV":  "env"

}
```

Finally, I managed to find the easiest way to generate a JSON file from Powershell.

```
$json = Get-Content "c:\users\bharat.gadade\desktop\test.json" | ConvertFrom-Json 
$json.SQS_QUEUE_URL = "https://que-url.com/server2"
$json.SQS_EVENTS_QUEUE_URL = "https://events-server.com/Server2/development_events"
$json.REGION = "region1 "
$json.BUCKET = "test-bucket"
$json.AE_WORK_PATH = "C:\workpath\path1"
$json.ENV = "env"
$json | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File "c:\users\bharat.gadade\desktop\test.json"
```

Comment: To add to this, for layered json data, you can reference the tags beneath the header with the period operator. 

so if your Json is like: 
{"Settings": {"AWS_REGION": "us-east-1" }}

you can use:
$json.Settings.AWS_REGION to set or read the entry!