# Github actions - pass secret variables to render ECS task definition action

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, github-actions

In order to deploy new task to ECS im using [amazon-ecs-render-task-definition](https://github.com/aws-actions/amazon-ecs-render-task-definition) GitHub action.
This action receives a task-definition.json as a parameter. This JSON contain secrets that i dont want to push, is there a way to inject some parameter to this JSON? Maybe from aws secrets manager?

For example - *task-definition.json*

```
{
 "containerDefinitions": [
  {
   "name": "wordpress",
   "links": [
     "mysql"
   ],
  "image": "wordpress",
  "essential": true,
  "portMappings": [
    {
      "containerPort": 80,
      "hostPort": 80
    }
  ],
  "memory": 500,
  "cpu": 10
},
{
  "environment": [
    {
      "name": "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD",
      "value": ****"password"**** // ITS A SECRET!
    }
  ],
  "name": "mysql",
  "image": "mysql",
  "cpu": 10,
  "memory": 500,
  "essential": true
}], 
 "family": "hello_world" }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently there is a build in solution for using aws-scrent-manager secrets:

```
"secrets": [
    {
      "name": "DATABASE_PASSWORD",
      "valueFrom": "arn:aws:ssm:us-east-1:awsExampleAccountID:parameter/awsExampleParameter"
    }
  ]
```

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-data-security-container-task/

Answer (score 5):

Another solution is to use `sed` to insert your secrets

So your workflow becomes something like -

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Add secrets to Task Definition
        run: |
          sed -i "s/<jwt_secret>/$JWT_SECRET/g" task.json 
          sed -i "s/<mongo_password>/$MONGO_PASSWORD/g" task.json 
        env:
          JWT_SECRET: ${{secrets.JWT_SECRET}}
          MONGO_PASSWORD: ${{secrets.MONGO_PASSWORD}}
```

Then you edit your to task.json to include the placeholders that sed will use for the replacement

```
{
  "ipcMode": null,
  "executionRoleArn": null,
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      ...
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "JWT_SECRET",
          "value": "<jwt_secret>"
        },
        {
          "name": "MONGO_PASSWORD",
          "value": "<mongo_password>"
        },
      ]
      ...
   }
  ]
}
```

Comment: it works on my json files @ali_wetrill. I use this process in multiple builds. I like it because I find GitHub secrets more streamlined than AWS - less cruft (IMHO).

Comment: Hmm on the first line under the run section I get 'sed: -e expression #1, char 64: unknown option to `s'. Any idea why? It's formatted exactly the same

Comment: @ali_wetrill The error "'sed: -e expression #1, char 64: unknown option to `s'" appears when there is a "/" in the env variable value because then sed expression will not resolve. 
e-g S3_FILENAME=testbucket123/.env
then the sed command:  
sed -i "s/<s3_secret>/$S3_FILENAME/g" task.json
becomes 
sed -i "s/<s3_secret>/testbucket123/.env/g" task.json

which is not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

All repos have a place to store their secrets, see [creating and using encrypted secrets](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/creating-and-using-encrypted-secrets). As for editing .json, preinstalled `jq` looks like an obvious choice here, or maybe `powershell` if you're more familiar with that (just remember about tweaking [-Depth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35865596/11998612)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Apparently there is a build in solution for using aws-secret-manager.